# Odata [EnableQuery] attribute makes EF Core crash on high requests amount

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, odata

In my Odata controller I Use [EnableQuery(EnsureStableOrdering = false)]. Stable ordering is because of some custom Order by which I need in my code. Example in the mentioned Issue above

The problem however is with the [EnableQuery] attribute in general. When I have this attribute in the controller on high load, which means more than 150 request in a minute at the same endpoint I get a lot of the following exception:

> "System.InvalidOperationException","Message":"A second operation was
> started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is
> usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same
> instance of DbContext."

I have used testing tool which send that kind of request to my endpoind (Result is around 240 requests in a minute with 1s delay between each) and most of the requests succeed, like maybe around 85% - 90% of them, however the failed requests get the exception above.

I needed some time to figure out what is happening, but when I remove the [EnableQuery] attribute everything was fine. No exception on any level of requests amount.

Here some code:

```
    public class OfficeDtoController : ODataController
    {
        private readonly IOfficesService _officesService;
        public OfficeDtoController(IOfficesService officesService)
        {
            _officesService = officesService;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [EnableQuery(EnsureStableOrdering = false)]
        public IActionResult GetOfficeDto(ODataQueryOptions<OfficeDto> queryOptions, Guid? id = null, string sortColumn = "", string sortOrder = "", int? top = null, int? skip = null)
        {
            IQueryable<OfficeDto> officeDto = _officesService.GetOffices(id, sortColumn, sortOrder, top, skip);
            return Ok(officeDto);
        }
    }


    public IQueryable<OfficeDto> GetOffices(Guid? id, string sortColumn, string sortOrder, int? top, int?     skip)
    {
        IQueryable<Office> query = dbSet;
        query = query
        .Where(z => !z.Deleted);
    
        var list = query.Select(x =>
            new OfficeDto()
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                ZipCode = x.ZipCode,
                Active = x..Active,
                Employees = x.XrefOfficesEmployees
                    .OrderBy(y => y.Order)
                    .Select(y => new IdAndName()
                    {
                        Value = y.EmployeeId,
                        Text = y.Employee.FirstName + " " + y.Employee.LastName,
                        Order = y.Order
                    })
                });
    
        switch (sortColumn)
        {
            case "employees":
                if (sortOrder == "desc")
                {
                    officeDto = officeDto.OrderByDescending(b => b.Employees.Select(a =>     a.Text).FirstOrDefault( ));
                }
                else
                {
                officeDto = officeDto.OrderBy(b => b.Employees.Select(a => a.Text).FirstOrDefault( ));
                }
        }
            
        return list;
    }
```

Here is the example URL:

> api/OfficeDto?$count=true&$top=20&$skip=0&$select=id,zipcode,employees&$filter=(active
> eq true)

Maybe there is problem in the communication between EF Core and Odata.

I use ASP.NET Wen API on NET 5 and the following NuGets:

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData 7.5.4
- Microsoft.Data.OData 5.8.4
- Microsoft.OData.Core 7.8.1
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.2

EDIT:

For ones who asked about DI:

```
    services.AddDbContext<MyContext>( );
    services.AddTransient<IOffcesService, OfficesService>( );
```

However I have tried to initialize everything in the Controller (DB Context and BusinessService) because at first my suggestion was about DI, however it didnt help.

Comment: How is the EF context injected? It looks like it's injected via a service class, how is that injected? What are the scopes you have used in the DI config in startup? For example, have you used `services.AddScoped<IInsuredsService, InsuredsService>()`?

Comment: How you register `DbContext` for DI?

Comment: Uninstall OData and use a naitive controller class before it is too late. You will never finish your project with OData.

Comment: @Sergey, interesting why?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv - I just had a big conversion with another person who are using OData controller. He had and still has  a big problem to post an object with [NotMapped] properties and with routing too. He told me he would never use OData again.

Comment: @Sergey, it is not OData problem, but EF. OData is a big benefit for dynamic grids.

Comment: Yes, It looks exactly as EF problem. As I have the absoulte same logic working perfectly in EF6